# Strange issue with Git fetching

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, bitbucket

Currently, I was facing problem on Git(bitbucket repo) Fetching while trying to pull the git changes. I was really unfamiliar with the problem happening like this. Please help me. I am sharing the error log of the problem. So, please provide me right direction of solution.

Message : `invalid advertisement of <!DOCTYPE html>`

Exception Stacktrace:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: invalid advertisement of <!DOCTYPE html>
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI.execute(FetchOperationUI.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI$1.run(FetchOperationUI.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: invalid advertisement of <!DOCTYPE html>
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.FetchOperation.run(FetchOperation.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI.execute(FetchOperationUI.java:99)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.PackProtocolException: invalid advertisement of <!DOCTYPE html>
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$HttpObjectDB.invalidAdvertisement(TransportHttp.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$HttpObjectDB.readAdvertisedImpl(TransportHttp.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.newDumbConnection(TransportHttp.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1105)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: This looks like the remote Git server responds with an HTML page. In order to verify that, you could enter the URL in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt comment. But, URL means, the repository url? if yes, then what should I look using the URL in a browser?

Comment: I want to make sure that I was using bitbucket.

Comment: Yes, the repository URL. If you enter the URL in a browser and an HTML page is shown, then either the URL is not a valid repository URL or your Git server sends a bogus resond. If possible share the URL here (with sensitive parts replaced).

Comment: Thank you so much. As per your suggestion, I have entered the URL in a browser and I saw there have site maintenance message like "We will be maintaining our site on Jan 06", which seems like some how additional content seen rather than before. So, do you think, it will causing the problem?

Comment: Bitbucket internally routes traffic based on user-agent. What (Java) client are you using there and how is it advertising itself? -- nevermind; jgit :-)

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE(puglin).

Answer (score 1):

I had also a similar problem. In my case the Git server had the following response:

`invalid advertisement of <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

As alredy suggested, i entered the Git repository URL into the browser, and the response was:

`The password to the repository is expired.`

After setting a new password, the problem was solved.